# .Net AES Padding Problem

Tags: .net, vb.net, aes, padding

im currently having a problem with the padding when decrypting a utf8 encoded string.

string length is not a multiple of 16, i use PKCS7 paddingmode

of course i do use the

> ```
> cs.FlushFinalBlock()
> ```

statement.

whats happing is, after decrypting, the stream wont hold the last block.
but when is use no paddingmode only while decrypting, the last block is there(with paddingbytes)

i have no clue whats wrong ;)

heres a bit code(vb.net im sry :D)

encryption

> ```
>             Dim rawPlaintext As Byte() = utf8.GetBytes(text)
>             aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7
>             Using ms As New MemoryStream()
>                 Using cs As New CryptoStream(ms, aes.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write)
>                     cs.Write(rawPlaintext, 0, rawPlaintext.Length)
>                     cs.FlushFinalBlock()
>                     ms.Position = 0
>                 End Using
>                 Return ms
>             End Using
> ```

decryption

> ```
>         aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7
>         
>         Using ms As New MemoryStream()
>             Using cs As New CryptoStream(ms, aes.CreateDecryptor(key, iv),
> ```
>
> CryptoStreamMode.Write)
>
> ```
>                 ciphertext.CopyTo(cs)
>                 ciphertext.Close()
>                 ms.Position = 0
>             End Using
>             Return ms            
>         End Using
> ```

hope u guys can help ;)

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see two problems with your code: The first is probably minor: I don’t think it is a good practice to pass around a disposed MemoryStream – do not return the MemoryStream, return only the contained array (use ms.ToArray()).

The second is worse: you do not need to call cs.FlushFinalBlock() explicitly, it is called automatically on Dispose (when leaving the Using block of the CryptoStream). However, in the second case you do not call it, *and* you reset position of the output stream while the decrypting CryptoStream has not finished yet. It means that only after changing the stream position, the CryptoStream gets to flushing the final block. You can work around that by adding cs.FlushFinalBlock() before ms.Position = 0 in the decryption code.

But, IMHO just remove the stream seek completely (possibly with FlushFinalBlock in the encryption code), and you should be fine, too.

Comment: thanks. to the first problem: in my full code i dont giv back a disposed memorystream ;) i didnt see the 2nd problem but its clear to me now. good job, it works now.